# Identify a trilogy about Earth and its colonies in a civil war

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I'm trying to  find this book trilogy.  It is set in the future when earth and its colonies are engaged in a civil war.  It deals with battles and strategies of the war, but also the politics involved with other species who align with opposing sides or meddle secretly. Seems like the second book was something like midworld(?).

Comment: Can you provider more detail? This is a little vague. Consider scenes, characters, plot, ..

Comment: i know its vague,sorry.read it when new,then lent it to a friend who disappeared.all i remember is i really liked it. if this is too hopeless i apoligise for wasting everyones time.thanx

Comment: Even a single scene that was memorable would help. Civil war with some colonies is just too common a theme without *something* to hang a guess on.

Comment: i think i may have found it on amazon.first book is beyond midway,in the double spiral war trilogy.sounds kind of like what i was searching for.gonna try that,once again thanx for your help.my old memory not what it used to be

Comment: If that is it, Sam, please answer your own question. Thanks!

Comment: ok,how do i do that?

Comment: @samdiveley In a day or two, you'll be able to post an answer.  Just use the text box at the bottom of this page.

Comment: Tip: if you reply to someone in the comments, use the @ symbol (plus their name) to alert them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the one I was looking for: the Double Spiral War trilogy by Warren Norwood.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like Alan Dean Foster's Humanx Commonwealth universe, which incidentally had a "Midworld" book (which some claimed was inspiration for James Cameron's *Avatar*).

But it was a big series, NOT a trilogy.

Comment: thanx,thats not it.was a big fan of his,would have remembered that.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be *[Insurrection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671720244)*?  In this story, the Fringe Worlds, at the risk of being effectively disenfranchised for the forseeable future (several centuries, at least) due to political wrangling by the Inner Worlds decide to break away.

The novel deals with the ensuing civil war, and the alien species that precipitate, interfere, or take advantage of it.

The book is part of a series called Starfire, and is set chronologically after it's two sequels, *In Death Ground* and *The Shiva Option*, which also deal heavily with inter-species politics during a massive war.

Comment: @jeff.thanx for reply. i found it myself.this sounds good,too